# Windows Store App Push Notifications via Azure Service Bus

Tags: windows, push-notification, windows-store-apps, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send a push notification to my Windows Store App developed in my laptop using VS 2013 Express. It's been few days now but I cannot figure out why I get "The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong" error. I use Windows Azure Notification Bus for this purpose. I use VS Server Explorer to send test notifications. I can see my laptop is being registered as a device in the Device Registration tab too. I tried the Azure portal as well, but the same error. However, when I try to connect to Service Bus Explorer 2.4.3.0 providing the connection string it throws below error.
<21:47:14> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Manage claim is required for this operation..TrackingId:c0c4fea2-08bc-4def-964c-ec6e690b7551_G45,TimeStamp:10/12/2014 4:17:11 PM. Method b__7e: retry 2 of 10.

FYI: I'm following below article step by step.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

Please help me. Thank you.
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like token is just expired. Make sure you obtain token **each time** application starts. In terms of the article you refer it means you  should call method InitNotificationsAsync() to do it. Here is that method:

```
private async void InitNotificationsAsync()
{
    var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

    var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string with listen access>");              
    var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);

    // Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
    if (result.RegistrationId != null)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Registration successful: " + result.RegistrationId);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }

}
```